# Internet access not working in Virtual PC

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc

I used the HD2VHD (from Sys Internals) wit the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) enabled.

However, when I try to run it, the Virtual PC guest doesn't have internet access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into network settings and change the adapter to your network adapter, in case it's set on local only networking:

[image]

Now try to access the Internet.

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately (forgot to mention) I tried that already (tried using the actual adapter and also the Shared Networking) both failed to provide inet access.

Comment: What message are you getting when you try to access websites using ping for example?

Comment: I can't get to that point because Windows boots up (this was converted from a HD to VHD using HD2VHD) and says it needs to activate, but then it can't access the internet and only option is to log off.
I ended up just punting on this (not critical to have this VHD running since I have the old computer available for a while). So I'm just voting this as the answer since for *most* people it'll solve the prob (has done that or me in the past).