# If you convert a HD to a VHD how do you activate Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd, disk2vhd

I used the HD2VHD (from Sys Internals) wit the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) enabled.

However, when I try to run it, the Virtual PC guest doesn't have internet access. And when I called Microsoft to activate it they said the hardware had changed and I'd need to change the Activation Key (which I can't do b/c I don't have the original install CD).

I'm guessing this would happen even if I had internet access. Also, I've tried changing the Networking option within Virtual PC ( per this [Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/98623) ) and still don't have internet access.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can change the activation key via telephone w/microsoft, it's fairly simple you just fallow the prompts enter in the code that comes up on your screen and enter the code the system comes back with.  You might be able to get the origional key from your software/hardware supplier depending on their records ect.